# Experiencing Under-Extrusion and Print Instability on CReality CR6 SE with Various PLA Filaments

Tags: troubleshooting, underextrusion, creality-cr-6

I am facing persistent issues with under-extrusion and print instability on my Creality CR6 SE 3D printer. Despite using different PLA filaments from various manufacturers such as Eryone, Jayo, Prusament, Redline, and Amazon Basic, I consistently encounter problems with thin lines and unreliable prints.

Notably, the same filaments perform well on my Prusa Mini, ruling out filament quality as the sole culprit.

[image]

Here are the key details:

- Running the latest Community Firmware.
- PLA filaments are stored adequately, ranging from a few weeks to several years old.
- Hotend temperature settings range from 205-215 °C with a 60 °C heated bed.
- Standard settings slightly modified for wider inner perimeters (0.6 mm) and higher temperature for stability.
- Occasional difficulties during filament changes, even with the extruder released and the nozzle adequately heated.

I have performed some troubleshooting steps, including changing filaments, adjusting Z offset, and ensuring proper storage conditions. However, the issue persists. I also cleaned the extruder. Could it helb to replace the PTFE tube with a Capricorn tube?

Are there additional steps I should consider or specific settings that could be impacting my print quality? Any insights or guidance would be greatly appreciated.

I have checked other questions on this site, but with no helpfull result for me.

Answer (score 1):

Try following [a guide on debugging under-extrusion](https://all3dp.com/2/under-extrusion-3d-printing-all-you-need-to-know/) all the way through.

The most obvious point you did not list in your question are: checking the mechanics of the extruder and cleaning the nozzle:

- Making sure the extruder gear theeth are clean and sharp
- Ensure proper spring tension is pressing the filament to the extruder gear
- Check if the motor has enough force/current to push the filament through your fingers if you press them together
- Calibrate the E-Steps
- Check that volumetric E is not enabled in your slicer settings.
- Make sure you can manually push filament through the heated nozzle without too much force
- Perform a cold pull or several
- etc.